# SQL Server : not allocating all memory that it has on disposal

Tags: sql-server

Yesterday, we moved from dedicated server to amazon AWS. And since then we see strange thing. Our SQL Server is not using more than 2.8GB of RAM, which is strange because on old server it always load everything to RAM. Our database is 289GB large, we have so many indexes etc. We are running on Microsoft SQL Server Standard edition, which should give us access to 128GB RAM for database usage.

What could it be the reason? Anyone experienced similar issue? Beside this, database seems to be working fine at the moment, although it had issue 1 time during 24 hours where it became completely unresponsive, so we restarted the SQL Server at that time. But something is strange, something is not right, because that ram should be filled to maximum as it always does.

Comment: There's no information here. What is the SQL Server max memory set to? How much memory is on you AWS server? Is it a VM or is it RDS?

Comment: Likely the issue here is in server configuration and/or limitations of the configured server type chosen in AWS. The answers to Nick.McDermaid's questions above should make that apparent. (If it's not RDS, then please also provide the instance type in AWS.)

Comment: Max memory is set to 327680 MB. AWS memory is 488 GB

Comment: instance type x1e.4xlarge

Comment: you can see here https://prnt.sc/w3y5l5

Comment: Exactly how do you determine how much memory your SQL Server is using? Task maneger is misleading if you have Lock Pages in Memory turned on for your SQL Server.

Comment: One thing to double-check, are you actually using the server? SQL Server doesn't just gobble up memory as soon as it's restarted, activity has to occur.

If it current shows only a few GB utilized, what happens after you SELECT * FROM <some big table>? Does it go up, or remain unchanged?

Comment: yes @TiborKaraszi actually task manager is misleading me in this case, because when i see total ram used its actually 268GB and sql server show only 3 gb now..

Comment: And how does "sql server show only 3 gb"? If we don't know where you see the value, we can't commend on the value you see.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the following counters:

```
select object_name,counter_name,instance_name,cntr_value/1024/1024 [GB] 
from sys.dm_os_performance_counters 
where counter_name like 'T%Server%'
```

Total Server memory - current consumption

Target Server memory - intention to consume next

Comment: this actually telling me correct ram usage!